# What is the best way to increase the dry time of a water based urethane paint?

Tags: painting, paint

I am trying to paint some cabinets with Behr Uerthane Satin Enamel. Spraying and foam rolling both left an orange peel texture. After sanding those down, I tried painting with a Purdh nylox brush and it’s leaving brush strokes, and I’m brushing thin & light so I don’t think my technique is the problem. I’m ok with brush strokes but the ones I’m getting seem too big for a self leveling paint. I’m pretty sure the paint is just drying too fast and doesn’t have a chance to level out. The paint specifically says do not thin, but is there any amount of water I can add that will still be ok to use the paint? Is an additive like floetrol a better option?

Comment: What is the temperature? Sunlight? How old is the urethane? And, do you have hidden areas or spare panels to experiment with? Water should work, but best to experiment. If you could add these infos to the question, that would be helpful.

Comment: In the shade, it’s been about 75 this week. The paint is brand new, just picked it up this week. First coat we sprayed it was 80 something and RH was about 85%. I’ll have to do some experimenting like you said

Comment: I was going to suggest increasing RH--but if you are already at 85% I don't think that will help. If it has been breezy or windy, perhaps an indoor location?

Comment: I’ve been doing it in the garage with the door open. I could shut the door but then the lighting wouldn’t be great. I was considering trying it inside since it is only 2 cabinets

Comment: Use floetrol and quit brushing. If you are spraying control your gun so you do not have to brush. I have sprayed using floetrol and had cabinets that looked like glass even in very warm weather. If you can’t control the gun JUST brush and the paint will relax , when you spray and brush you overwork the paint and get poor results.

Comment: you don't want to add any more than 20% water. A high-quality hand-powered mister (often sold for plants) can evenly and very gently wet the "painted" surface to buy time.

Comment: Got the floetrol. I’m going to sand and spray tomorrow when it’s supposed to be pretty humid. And to clarify, I have been using one tool at a time. I haven’t been back brushing when I spray or roll.